# Mock json data for Angular application

Tags: angularjs, json, gruntjs

I am working on Angular application where my APIs are not ready yet. I want to replicate my same API url with mock data. for example, if I call

```
/v1/users
```

with $resource then it should return json response with some data and later on when my APIs will be ready I can just remove my mock data and same API url will work with live data. I can put a flag as well to switch between mock and live data. Most of the solutions I found were for $httpbackend or unit testing but my requirement is NOT for unit testing. I know Angular-mocks does the something like that and I have added its bower component in my application. I have also added one folder outside my app folder with a json file, but what should I do so that if I call it, it gives me some json data.

Comment: This is kind like a server but it is reaally simple to use: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Did you consider firebase?

Comment: @FelipeT. I tried json-server but I can run only one json file with command "json-server db.json". How about if I need to run more files? is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Rahul why would you need that? You can declare all the routes of your app in the db.json file. Can you exaplain better?

Comment: I have multiple JSON objects and I need APIs like /v1/users, /v1/requests and so on. Only way I found is to write all the objects in one JSON file which is making my file quite huge. I want to create files like user.json, requests.json and so on, so that I could manage my data object easily.